# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'value' of undefined error for const city

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error in const city Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

```
handleClick = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const api=await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=563f12881628bc03a04f230c259dd4f9`);
    const rtr = await api.json();
   this.setState({
     temperature:rtr.main.temp,
     humidity:rtr.main.humidity,
     city:rtr.name,
     country:rtr.sys.country
   });
  }
```

expected to fetch city by api calling

Comment: elements.city is undefined, can you console.log e.target.elements?

Answer (score 0):

You should add if statements to check if the city exists.

```
handleClick = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = !!e.target.elements.city && e.target.elements.city.value;
    if (!city) {
      return;
    }

    const api=await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=563f12881628bc03a04f230c259dd4f9`);
    const rtr = await api.json();
   this.setState({
     temperature:rtr.main.temp,
     humidity:rtr.main.humidity,
     city:rtr.name,
     country:rtr.sys.country
   });
  }
```